# Creating an array using grep command over a file

Tags: unix

i am using grep command to create an array using data from a file.
These is a sample from a file abc.xyz

```
[abc] Hello world
[abc] qwertyuy
[qwe] poiuyttrr
[abc] Zzxcvzxvxczv
```

I want to store each of the lines in an array which is having word'[abc]' in the begining
I am using the following command

```
grep -n "\[abc\]" abc.xyz
```

And storing it in a variable, But the varaiable is got getting stored as an array. 
Please suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have Bash or Korn shell:

```
var=( $(grep -n "\[abc\]" abc.xyz) )
```

The `var=( … )` creates the array.  The `$( … )` executes a command and the result is tokenized.  Note that the tags etc will be split into separate words.  For your input file, the output is:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${var[@]}"
1:[abc]
Hello
world
2:[abc]
qwertyuy
4:[abc]
Zzxcvzxvxczv
$
```

If you want to split on newlines, you have to play with `IFS`:

```
$ old="$IFS"
$ IFS=$'\n'    # Bash - may not be available in ksh
$ var=( $(grep -n "\[abc\]" abc.xyz) )
$ IFS="$old"
$ print "%s\n" "${var[@]}"
1:[abc] Hello world
2:[abc] qwertyuy
4:[abc] Zzxcvzxvxczv
$
```